# Shared legend in subplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, julia

I'm trying to translate some of my R code to Julia. I mainly struggle with the difference in plotting as I'm very used to ggplot2.

There I can do:

```
mpg %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = cyl, color = manufacturer)) + 
geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~class)
```

With this I get subplots, consistent x- and y-axes, a shared legend, and much more.
How would I achieve this with Julia, say the GR backend?

Update: The `mpg` data set looks like:

```
# A tibble: 234 × 11
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class  
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>  
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact
# … with 224 more rows
```

and the output I'm after would look something like:
[image: R plot]

Comment: Could you maybe post the output of that command as well to show those that have never used ggplot2 what you're after? My gut feel is that this won't work with Plots.jl without quite a bit of manual intervention, but it's hard to say without a concrete example of the final product.

Comment: worth knowing is that you can use ggplot2 in Julia too. Just use the RCall package and you have your ggplot2 command in Julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this at present might be with [Makie.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl), which gives you very granular control over the plotting process. For example:

```
# using GLMakie # If you want an interactive plot window and raster graphics
# or
using CairoMakie # If you want to save vector graphics

fig = Figure()
ax1 = Axis(fig[1, 1])
ax2 = Axis(fig[1, 2])
ax3 = Axis(fig[2, 1:2])
l1 = lines!(ax1, 0..10, sin, color=:red)
l2 = lines!(ax2, 0..10, cos, color=:blue)
l3 = lines!(ax3, 0..10, sqrt, color=:green)
ax1.ylabel = "amplitude"
ax3.ylabel = "amplitude"
ax3.xlabel = "time"
Legend(fig[1:2, 3], [l1, l2, l3], ["sin", "cos", "sqrt"])
fig
```

and optionally

```
save("filename.ext", fig)
```

yields
[image]

There are a number of good examples and tutorials in https://makie.juliaplots.org/v0.15.1/tutorials/basic-tutorial/
and
https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/

If you tend to like the "grammar of graphics" style, you might also check out [AlgebraOfGraphics.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/AlgebraOfGraphics.jl), which is built on top of Makie, or (though I haven't tried it in some time) [Gadfly.jl](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl), which was actually one of the first plotting packages in Julia.

Comment: This is a great tip. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've been playing around with Makie a bit but still wasn't able to recreate the ggplot output. Could you take the example above a recreate it in Julia?

Comment: I'd need an image of what you're trying to recreate; I was left to guess what you are looking for since I don't have R installed.

Comment: I've updated the original post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [Gadfly](http://gadflyjl.org/) using `Geom.subplot_grid`, but it doesn't seem possible to spread the plots across multiple rows as with `facet_wrap`.

```
using RDatasets
using Gadfly

mpg = dataset("ggplot2", "mpg")

plot(mpg, x = :Displ, y = :Cyl, color = :Manufacturer,
    xgroup = :Class,
    Geom.subplot_grid(Geom.point),
    )
```

[image: MPG figure using Julia and Gadfly]